# MediaWiki QuickTemplate class - Where to find references?

Tags: reference, arguments, mediawiki, skinning, mediawiki-extensions

I'm new to MediaWiki skin design. I have found these two functions being used heavily.

```
QuickTemplate::html($str)
QuickTemplate::text($str)
```

These are used in execute() function in the custom Template class, as `$this->html($str)` and `$this->text($str)`

I'm pretty ok with their functionality. But, so far, I haven't found a reference for the list of string arguments fed through the $str parameter. I've seen them being used in templates with various arguments like, `$this->html( 'headelement' )`, or `$this->text( 'pageLanguage' )`. My question is how do we exactly know the the argument is `'headelement'` ? Is there a complete list of such arguments? Not sure whether I'm missing some part of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you try the [QuickTemplate Class Reference](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classQuickTemplate.html) and [Using QuickTemplate in extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:QuickTemplate#Using_QuickTemplate_in_extensions)?

The functions html() and text() don't really do anything, they seem just a way to supposedly "abstract" the handling of HTML strings vs. all other strings: text() escapes the HTML a bit. Mostly a historical thing.

As the manual says, please don't use QuickTemplate :), follow the [skinning template](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:QuickTemplate#Using_QuickTemplate_in_extensions).